# Error registering XAML-build controller to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I get the following error when I try to register a TFS 2017 Build controller against Visual Studio Team Services:

> Error provisioning default service account: Access denied: John Doe
>   needs the following permission(s) in the Identity security namespace
>   to perform this action: Edit identity information. Additional details:
>   security token: a5ca35eb-148e-4ccd-bbb3-d31576d75958, permission bits
>   required: 2.

The VSTS-account was just created and is connected to Azure AD. My user is member of the Project Collection Administrators-group for the VSTS-account.

The "Project Collection Service Accounts"-group in VSTS does not contain a user named "Account Service (XXX)" - it does not look like it has been created automatically.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and/or have guidance on how to resolve it?

Comment: I recommended that you can use VNext build, refer to this article to setup a build agent on your server https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows. Regarding migrate from XAML build to new builds: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/migrate-from-xaml-builds

Comment: BTW, there is Account Service (XXX) in one of my VSTS, but others don't have, so I can reproduce this issue too.

Comment: The plan is to migrate the XAML-builds to vNext later this year.
Are you able to confirm whether the missing "Account Service (XXX)" is due to a bug?